# How would the set of this linear system of equations look?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I'd like to know how a set of this would look?

$$x_{1}+x_{2}=3$$

$$-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$$

It's easy to make one set, where you calculate the solutions of this linear system (in this case we have $0$ and $3$).
This set would be $S=\left\{0;3\right\}$

How about the other set? I'm very excited to know that, I would say it would be:

$$S=\left\{x_{1},x_{2} \in \mathbb{R}|x_{1}+x_{2}=3 \wedge -x_{1}+2x_{2}=6\right\}$$

Would this be correct or is it written different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ***solution* set** to the system of linear equations $$x_1 + x_2 = 3 \\ -x_1 + 2x_2=6$$ is the set of all ordered pairs $(x_1, x_2)$ that simultaneously solve both equations.  The only such ordered pair in this case would be $(0,3)$, so the solution set would be $\{(0,3)\}$.

To write the solution set out in set-builder notation, you'd write $$\{(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2 \mid a+b=3 \wedge -a+2b=6\}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just a question; why did you write $\in \mathbb{R}^{2}$? Is it because there are these two elements $a,b$ that belong to it? Would it be wrong to just write $\mathbb{R}$ instead?

Comment: $\Bbb R^2$ is the set of all ordered pairs of real numbers.  $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers.  In this case, the solution set is a subset of the $\Bbb R^2$ -- that is, any solution will be *two* numbers (in a specific order), not just one.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure if I understood correctly. What if we had elements $(a,b,c)$? We would write $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ then? Or is it just $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ always when there is more than $1$ element?

Comment: That is correct.  Here's an example of the difference between $\{0,3\}$ and $\{(0,3)\}$.  $(x_1,x_2)=(0,3)$ is a solution to *your* system of equations.  But $\{0,3\}$ is the solution set to $x^2-3x=0$.  Notice that any solution to this second system will just be *one* number.  But there are two such numbers that work.

Comment: @Bye_World I think that to say "the solution will be two numbers..." may be misleading, as the *actual, formal* answer shoould be "the solution is an ordered **pair** (of real numbers, in this case)..." .

Comment: @Bye_World To what you refer when you say "That is correct"? $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ or $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: @DonAntonio I did mention that the solution set is in $\Bbb R^2$.  But I'm not sure OP knows what an ordered pair is so I'm trying to be more informal with my language.

Comment: @cnmesr I don't think you had that last question when I answered.  $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb R^3$.  The object $(a,b,c)$ is called an "ordered triple of real numbers".  The set of all real ordered triples is $\Bbb R^3$.  Then $(a,b,c,d)\in\Bbb R^4$, $(a,b,c,d,e)\in\Bbb R^5$, etc.