# Did I draw this set correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given was this little linear system of equations:

$$I:x_{1}+x_{2}=3$$

$$II:-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$$

and we were supposed to specify its implicit and explicit set.

Here is it:

$$S=\left\{0;3\right\}$$

$$S=\left\{(x_{1},x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R}^{2}|x_{1}+x_{2}=3 \wedge -x_{1}+2x_{2}=6\right\}$$

**Now we are supposed to draw these sets and I'm not sure how it's done?**

I first thought about drawing both these linear systems but then realized they aren't functions so..

I would do it like this but not sure:

$$I:x_{1}=-x_{2}+3$$

$$II:x_{1}=2x_{2}-6$$

Not sure if I should form to $x_{1}$ or rather $x_{2}$..?

[image]

Comment: Refer to your yesterday question (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979168)

Comment: They way to write the equation doesn't matter, provided you represent all the points in these sets.

Comment: What's the point refering to it? I have mentioned its results here and that should be enough :P

Comment: @Yves Daoust alright that's really good to know! Still from my drawing I cannot really see the intersection or the set $S=\left\{0;3\right\}$. Or it just represents the intersection of the two lines at coordinates $(0;3)$, as you can see from the drawing?

Comment: The intersection set is $\{(3,0)\}$.

Comment: Ok then it seems to be correct right? I have drawn it as shown here.