# How do you draw the set of this cartesian product correctly?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

> $S$ is the set of all $(x_{1},x_{2}) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$
>   with $x_{1}+x_{2} \geq 3$ and $-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$
>
> Write the set S and draw it.

$$S=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R\mid x_1+x_2\geq 3 \text{ and } -x_1+2x_2=6\}$$

Okay I have the set and now I have to draw this set. I only need to know explanation how to do it.

So I would just form $-x_{1}+2x_{2}=6$ to $x_{1}=2x_{2}-6$ and draw this linear function.

But what about the inequality? Calculate values $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$
then also just draw it and mark the areas that are defined?

Is the idea correct how I plan to do it?

Comment: To handle the inequality, first change it into an equality, and draw a line as you did with the other condition. Then everything on one side of that line satisfies the inequality.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Any polynomial equation in two variables makes a curve that divides the plane into regions (a line divides the plane into two halves, a circle into an outside and an inside, and so on). The corresponding inequality is, for each region, either satisfied on the whole region, or not satisfied anywhere in that region.

Comment: It's the fourth time you post something around the **same** elementary subject in a few days ; for example (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1979835).

Comment: @JeanMarie Is it forbidden?